# Печать всего содержимого тега table

Tags: jquery, print, table

Есть кнопка

```
<a href='#' id='print'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span></a>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при клике по данной кнопке, начиналась печать всей таблицы тега . Данных может быть сколько угодно, от 10 до 1000. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 6):

Мой любимый способ напечатать любой элемент, простой, как табуретка.

План таков:

1. На лету создаём в DOM копию элемента
2. Вставляем её в специально заготовленную секцию в корне документа
3. Скрываем всё в корне, кроме неё
4. Печатаем видимое содержимое окна: `window.print()`
5. Восстанавливаем видимость, вычищаем копию

```js
function printById(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!el) return;
  var elCopy = el.cloneNode(true);
  // Получаем ранее созданную или создаём впервые секцию для печати
  var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');
  if (!printSection) {
    printSection = document.createElement("div");
    printSection.id = "printSection";

    document.body.appendChild(printSection);
  }
  //
  printSection.innerHTML = '';
  printSection.appendChild(elCopy);
  // прячем всё кроме printSection
  var children = document.body.children, i, el;
  for (i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    el = children[i];
    el.style._display = el.style.display;
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
  printSection.style.display = 'block';

  // Печать
  window.print();

  // Восстанавливаем видимость  
  for (i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    el = children[i];
    el.style.display = el.style._display;
    delete el.style._display;
  }
  printSection.style.display = 'none';
  // Очищаем DOM
  printSection.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: silver;
}

@media print {
* {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://vanilla-js.com/?download"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Page title</h3>
    <table id="userlist" border=1>
      <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>Alice</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>Bob</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td><td>Charlie</td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <div>
      <button onclick="printById('userlist')">Print...</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

PS: *Вместо `jquery` был использован [vanillaJs](http://vanilla-js.com/). Убедитесь, что вы не забыли его подключить.*

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня почему то не работает..

Comment: Сказать "Не работает" значит ничего не сказать. Опишите поведение, наличие ошибок и тд

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет. Библиотеку подключил. Нажимаю на кнопку, и ничего не происходит

Comment: Сниппет работает?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел простой и рабочий вариант!
Главное, не забыть подключить jquery, а дальше все просто.

```
 <a href='#' id='print' onclick='printData()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span></a>
```

Вот сама кнопка. Ниже весь код.

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable"); //Указываем ID элементадля печати
   newWin = window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
```

Вот и всё!